# finding the height of text in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

Code:

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [300, 210]);
 doc.fromHTML(text, 15, 15, {
        'width': 175, 
 });

 doc.text(10, HEIGHT, 'What should be height so it does not overlap with previous text');
```

Here is my code but two text are overlapping each other? Is there any method to know the value of HEIGHT(know where previous text is ending) such that two does not overlap? text html is not static it changes.

Comment: Any solution? I've been digging the docs for a while... nothing...

Comment: @Zac Not sure if you guys are still looking for a solution but I found `getTextDimensions(text, options)` to give me the width and height.